# Log4j prints error stacktrace on local but not on server

Tags: java, logging, amazon-ec2, slf4j, slf4j-api

I have a Java application running on Amazon EC2 instance. And I am using Apache log4j logging framework to maintain `ERROR` as well as `DEBUG` logs for my application.

But recently I'm not able to log error stack trace using `logger.error(String Message, Throwable t)`.

I tried to log alternatively like this,

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sWriter));
logger.error("Exception occured while fetching count from DB", sWriter);
```

But `.log` file only displays the message `Exception occurred while fetching count from DB`

My `log4j.properties` file looks like this

```
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender

# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=${loggingType}, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=${logFile}
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] %c %M - %m%n
```

If I run the application locally, I can see error print stack trace but same does not work on my Amazon EC2 instance.

log4j version is 1.7.2

JDK version is 1.7.0_151

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

instead of

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

The first one allows you to use the name of the actual class in all classes throughout the inheritance hierarchy.